# Cannot open Submin SVN homepage with "mod_authn_dbd" error after installed in CentOS

Tags: centos

I'm following offical `Submin` guide [here](https://ssl.supermind.nl/collab/projects/submin/browser/INSTALL.CentOS?rev=50a022b5440b3ebe782425786affe1e8c5e33e1b) to install Submin on my `CentOS release 6.7 (Final)` server.

I'm stuck at the final steps - opening `http://<my local ip>/svn` to view the outcome SVN website, I got the error `No mod_authn_dbd found` as below snapshot.

As you may come over this before, please share. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error informs us that the module is not loaded, we can use the following command to install and load them.

```
sudo apt-get install subversion subversion-tools libapache2-svn
sudo a2enmod dav_svn
sudo a2enmod 'xxxxx modules which you want to load'
```

Once they are loaded you can check what else is failing using the following command

```
sudo submin2-admin /var/lib/submin diagnostics
```

For more info you use use this detail installation guide
[Installation Guide](https://ssl.supermind.nl/collab/projects/submin/browser/INSTALL)

Please feel free to edit the answer and make it more appropriate for everyone.